# Does an async function requires the inner functions marked as async too?

Tags: dart

```
Future<void> doIt() async {
    // here are some operations which are not marked as async
    // but still take some time
    print ('done');
    return;
}
```

Should the above function execute as async even though the inner operation are not marked as async if I run it like below?

```
await doIt();
print(next output);
```

Will the output be

```
next output
done
```

or

```
done
next output
```

Or, in other words,  is there a way to ***execute regular function as async function***?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dart - make long running synchronous function asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61737126/dart-make-long-running-synchronous-function-asynchronous)

Comment: @jamesdlin I will check it but there are two answers and no one submitted as solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Future/async/await in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49537996/future-async-await-in-dart)